# Can I use Google Apps to bulk e-mail my customers?

Tags: email, smtp, g-suite

I use Google Apps for my company's e-mail. I want to start sending out bulk e-mails. Is it allowed to be sending out via a dedicated google apps account like do-not-reply@domain.com?

Are there any real negatives other than dev time to doing it this way (and maybe not seeing logs - would be able to see undeliverables though)? Is there a suggested batch size?

I'm not averse to using a dedicated resource like Constant Contact or iContact or something. I haven't done email marketing in a while, so I am not sure what is best.

**edit 1**
What would be a recommended service for delivering ~1000 emails like once a week?

Comment: regarding your edit, per the FAQ, we don't do product or service recommendations.

Comment: Mailchimp. Next question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll get yourself shut down fairly quickly if you do something like this.

There are per-account per-day max limit on the number of emails you can send - I believe it's in the neighborhood of 500.  See the [Google Apps Sending Limits](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852) documentation.

You'll need to consider either running your own mailer or using the services of one of the many companies that specialize in bulk email.

Comment: It is worth noting that, in order to send *legitimate* bulk e-mail with a strict double opt-in process, automated list management is basically essential.

Comment: thx, wouldn't be much more than 500 I don't think.

Comment: @timpone - You'll still get shut down eventually. As soon as Google gets a hit that you're using their service for bulk mailing, it'll be over.

Answer (score -2):

Google Apps does indeed allow for their service to be used for email marketing purposes, albeit limited to 10,000 unique recipients per day.

Various advice is offered by Google in respect of utilising the service for email marketing. Suggestion like staggering your send over multiple days. Using Google Groups as one way to bypass the limitations of 10,000 recipients (intended for messaging users WITHIN an organisation/company). They also direct users to the Google Apps Marketplace and solutions by 3rd party developers wh

This all of course assumes your sending practices are based on permission and that you adhere to the bulk sending guidelines and best practices that Google publishes.